# PHPUnit backupGlobals option : what is it for?

Tags: php, phpunit

I don't understand the definition and usage of the `backupGlobals` option in PhpUnit. The PhpUnint 9.6 documentation states that :

*[Doc for The XML Configuration File](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/9.6/configuration.html)* :

> "PHPUnit can optionally backup all global and super-global variables before each test and restore this backup after each test".

What does that mean exactly ? What is "*backuped*" : the global and super-global of my test code, or the ones from my production code ? How are they backup ? Why would I want or need to do such an operation ? Can someone give a working example that would highlight the difference between enabling this feature or not ?

The documentation gives no more details and I did not find any explanations on the net.

*[Doc for The XML Configuration File](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/9.6/configuration.html)*

> "The `@backupGlobals` enabled annotation can be used on the class level to enable this operation for all tests of a test case class:"

Here, I understand the fact that we can use this option whether at the configuration file level (for all test), or at the class level (overriding the previous one). But without knowing its purpose, it does not help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In PHP every code has access to global (`$GLOBALS`) and super global variables  (`$_SERVER`, `$_GET`, ...); see [**Superglobals**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

This makes any PHP code relying on it prone to side effects when those variables are accessed (both read or write). Unit testing needs a well defined system under test. Backing up those globals before a test (and restoring them afterwards) can help with that; to test units in isolation.

How that is implemented is within PHPUnit, which source code should be available to you so that you can inspect it specifically. IIRC it makes a copy of those values and then restores them afterwards. That's meant by backup, it's not a file system backup, but in the PHPUnit runner process memory, e.g. using an `Array` similar to that `$GLOBALS` etc. .

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this does not help me much. I'm know what are globals and superglobals in php. What I'm looking for is a working example that would help me understand the use of this phpunit option. For now, I don't see why and how I must backing up those variables during the phpunit process.

Comment: @vittorio: Yes, thanks for commenting, and thinking about the working example: First of all this is a configuration option/setting that is effective during running a test/s or suite/s or overall. So the use case is to en- or disable it. About how: there is nothing you need to do apart of configuring it. About why: Test isoloation. It is normally that when you realize that your test degrades from global variable pollution, you can enable it to stabilize the test/s again. Backup then is before the test (automatically) and GLOBALS will be restored after the test has run. Does this help?